# Authentication and Authorization in Local Network UWP Apps

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp, local

I want to develop a (Universal Windows Platform) UWP app that will run locally. But another requirement is that 2 or more of the same UWP apps will be on another PC as a client. In the same local network, the database will be using sharing across all devices.

And of course, authentication and authorization will be needed on my UWP App.

I've done those in Web Apps using supported libraries according to the used language. But no idea how to implement it in UWP and local-network applications.

I've targeted to use UWP C# and MySQL database.

What would be the architecture of the App and popular tech stack to use because I'm not familiar with the C# world? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can have a Service (WCF/Restful) that does Database Record Management. UWP frontend apps can then work with the API's

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Do you mean as saying in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service ?

Comment: Windows Communication Foundation (WCF).

Comment: Any updates? You could share your solution and mark it as answer if you have solved it.

Comment: I used Java Spring Boot, wrote APIs, and used them from the local UWP apps. To parse the JSON in UWP C#, I used the `Newtonsoft.Json` package.